Attempting to use the imx8 caam causes "device-mapper: table: 252:0: crypt: Error decoding and setting key"
I'm following the instruction in AN12714, using a vendor-supplied kernel, but I get an error:
root@smarcimx8mq4g:~/keyctl_caam# caam-keygen create randomkeyCCM ccm -s 24

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~/keyctl_caam# ls /data/caam/
randomkeyCCM  randomkeyCCM.bb

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~/keyctl_caam# cat /data/caam/randomkeyCCM | keyctl padd logon logkey: @s
131470369

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~/keyctl_caam# keyctl list @s
2 keys in keyring:
209553926: --alswrv     0 65534 keyring: _uid.0
131470369: --alsw-v     0     0 logon: logkey:

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~/keyctl_caam# dd if=/dev/zero of=encrypted.img bs=1M count=32
32+0 records in
32+0 records out
33554432 bytes (34 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.130898 s, 256 MB/s

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~/keyctl_caam# losetup /dev/loop0 encrypted.img

root@smarcimx8mq4g:~/keyctl_caam# dmsetup -v create encrypted --table "0 $(blockdev --getsz /dev/loop0) crypt capi:tk(cbc(aes))-plain :36:logon:logkey: 0 /dev/loop0 0 1 sector_size:512"

[  375.241675] device-mapper: table: 252:0: crypt: Error decoding and setting key
[  375.248938] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table

device-mapper: reload ioctl on encrypted (252:0) failed: Invalid argument
Command failed.

I've noticed some errors in dmesg:
root@smarcimx8mq4g:~# dmesg | grep caam
[    1.478230] caam 30900000.crypto: device ID = 0x0a16040100000000 (Era 9)
[    1.484947] caam 30900000.crypto: job rings = 3, qi = 0
[    1.540281] caam algorithms registered in /proc/crypto
[    1.546474] caam 30900000.crypto: caam pkc algorithms registered in /proc/crypto
[    1.553892] caam 30900000.crypto: registering rng-caam
[    1.563166] caam 30900000.crypto: wanted 32 bytes, got 0
[    1.568515] caam 30900000.crypto: wanted 64 bytes, got 0
[    1.573872] caam 30900000.crypto: wanted 128 bytes, got 0
[    1.609565] caam 30900000.crypto: wanted 32 bytes, got 16
[    1.634284] caam 30900000.crypto: wanted 64 bytes, got 16
[    1.659004] caam 30900000.crypto: wanted 128 bytes, got 16
[    1.666795] Device caam-keygen registered
[    1.681278] caam-snvs 30370000.caam-snvs: violation handlers armed - non-secure state
[    7.160643] error: exports duplicate symbol caam_dump_sg (owned by kernel)
[    7.223265] error: exports duplicate symbol caam_dump_sg (owned by kernel)
[    7.851871] error: exports duplicate symbol caam_dump_sg (owned by kernel)
[    7.923480] error: exports duplicate symbol caam_dump_sg (owned by kernel)
[    7.980089] error: exports duplicate symbol caam_dump_sg (owned by kernel)

Of particular concern is:
[    1.681278] caam-snvs 30370000.caam-snvs: violation handlers armed - non-secure state

Should the "black blob" keys work before I have got secure boot working, or is that the root of the issue.
